# Printing multidimensional arrays from a vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, multidimensional-array

I have multiple multidimensional arrays stored in a vector, but I seem to effectively print them. I always get either the first line of the array or no output depending on what I try.

This is how I attempt to print out the multidim arrays:

```
     int vecSize = myVec.size();

     for (int x = 0; x < vecSize; x++){
       for (int y=0; y <vecSize; y++){
           cout<<myVec[x][y]<<endl;
        }
      }
```

This is how I place the arrays in the vector:

```
    myVec.push_back(myMultiDArray);
```

***Any suggestions on how to improve this?***

Comment: What is `myVec`? It is quite confusing because usually vectors have one dimension, and you are doing `myVec[x][y]`.

Comment: @luk32 myVec is the vector I am using to store the multiD Arrays.

Comment: Then why are you using double indexing for it - `myVec[x][y]` doesn't make much sense. You should iterate over the vector to get the arrays. And then iterate over the elements of the arrays to print them. What you have now looks like a big mess to be honest.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that every vector that is an element of myVec has the same number of elements in myVec itself? - if not you run the risk of accessing out of bounds elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the loop condition: the inner loop iterates up to the same bound as the outer one. This is almost certainly wrong, it should iterate to the size of the current line vector. Like this:

```
for (size_t x = 0, vecSize = myVec.size(); x < vecSize; x++) {
    std::vector<int>& curVec = myVec[x];

    for (size_t y = 0, curSize = curVec.size(); y < curSize; y++) {
        cout << curVec[y] << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n";
}
```

This code will work flawlessly for any shape of the 2D array.